# Can't add a child to GameScene, only to a SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to create a SKSpriteNode from a class (Planets), to my GameScene, when a button is pressed. My problem is that the border doesn't appear on screen.

`class Planets: SKSpriteNode, EventListenerNode, InteractiveNode {`

```
var gameScene: GameScene!

func didMoveToScene(){
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    gameScene = (SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as! GameScene)
}

func interact() {
    print("hi \(self.name ?? "Planet X")")
    let border = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.gray, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
    border.name = "border"
    border.zPosition = 100
    border.position = CGPoint(x: gameScene.frame.size.width/2, y: gameScene.frame.size.height/2)
    gameScene.addChild(border)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    interact()
}
```

`}`

However, if I use self.addChild,(self meaning the Planets class) it works, so it works if I add the border to a SKSpriteNode, but I don't want that because the size differ, the position differ too. I just want to add it to my GameScene.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the `Planets` class is creating its own copy of `GameScene` with this line here:

```
gameScene = (SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as! GameScene)
```

That copy is never presented and so it's never visible and neither is the border that was added to it.

If `Planets` is a child of `GameScene` then I would try referencing the parent of the `Planets` node when you add the border like this:

```
func interact() {
    print("hi \(self.name ?? "Planet X")")

    guard let gameScene = self.parent as? GameScene else {
        print("Error: could not get the parent scene")
        return
    }

    let border = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.gray, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
    border.name = "border"
    border.zPosition = 100
    border.position = CGPoint(x: gameScene.frame.size.width/2, y: gameScene.frame.size.height/2)
    gameScene.addChild(border)
}
```